# Creating a Line based on the outline of two polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, features, line, create

I have two polygons and where they meet, I need to create a new line shapefile. I have used the trace method, but it keeps giving me a polygon. Under construction tools, "line" is not an option.

Do I just have to use the "Draw Tool"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Intersect tool should work. Be sure to set the output type to "Line" as shown below. 
[image]

The purple line below is the output of the Intersect tool representing the location where the two polygons meet.

[image]